# I get SassError when using ampersand in my react scss module

Tags: css, sass, create-react-app

I'm getting this error on my scss file.

[image]

[image]

---

What I did is to disable TypeScript, eslint, and prettier as I thought this is coming from them but no. How should I resolve this? Also my syntax is correct. This is a valid scss.

Having this error won't compile my React app.

```
SassError: Invalid CSS after "...px solid green;": expected "}", was "&.__form: {"
        on line 4 of /Users/raphaelgako/Documents/aRtoo/dev_p/ggpo/client/src/components/SignupLogin/Signup/Signup.module.scss
>>   border: 10px solid green;

   ---------------------------^
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  },
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a typo in your styles, where you defined the inner class with a colon in it (`&.__form:`). So you need to change it like this:

```
.SignupContainer {
  border: 10px solid green;
  
  &.__form {
    border: 10px solid blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: HOLY B$*#& dude you dont know how I was struggling. I skip lunch for this and took late dinner. thanks man. I need to go sleep. thanks thanks thanks thank you times a million.

Comment: @aRtoo No worries, we all struggled with simpler bugs